# Find which monitor or screen contains mouse pointer - swift, macos

Tags: swift, macos, screen, mouse, multiple-monitors

I would like to find out which monitor the mouse is on so I can create a window on that monitor.

This is different to which is the main screen, because `NSScreen.main` returns whichever screen has the active window inside of it (an easy way to tell is which monitor's menubar is opaque, the others will be dimmed slightly).

From what I can tell there's no direct way to get this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Answering my own question since I found the answer - this might be helpful to someone else.

It's not too difficult to find which screen/monitor the mouse is on, but you do have to iterate through each screen in order to do so.

#### Swift 4

```
func getScreenWithMouse() -> NSScreen? {
  let mouseLocation = NSEvent.mouseLocation
  let screens = NSScreen.screens
  let screenWithMouse = (screens.first { NSMouseInRect(mouseLocation, $0.frame, false) })

  return screenWithMouse
}
```

#### Objective C

A similar way to get the same result in Objective-C would be:

```
NSPoint mouseLoc = [NSEvent mouseLocation];
NSEnumerator *screenEnum = [[NSScreen screens] objectEnumerator];
NSScreen screen;
while ((screen = [screenEnum nextObject]) && !NSMouseInRect(mouseLoc, 
                                                           [screen frame], NO));
```

Comment: @Moritz it sure does compile! I'm already using it :) Are you sure you're using Swift 4? (found a typo in it)

Comment: Ah, yeah, sorry, I was using Swift 3. Indeed it works with Swift 4. :)